# Upload code to ESP32/Arduino while pySerial is running

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, esp32

I'm working on a project that an ESP32 module needs to read some value from a sensor and send it to a python code using pySerial. My code in constantly reading from the serial, as I can send data to it at any time. The problem is that the python program cannot be stopped because it's a server, but i still want to upload code whenever I want to the ESP32 module. Also, I'm sending data via serial on the void setup() function, so I need the python code to be running when the code is uploaded to the board, that is, when the setup() function runs.
I know I can't upload my code to the board while the serial port is being used by pySerial, but is there any way around? Like closing the connection while I'm uploading the code or when there is no data to be sent?

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
import serial
import json

ser = serial.Serial("COM6", 115200)

while(1):
    if(ser.in_waiting > 0):
        leitura = ser.read_until(b'}').decode('ascii')
        data = json.loads(leitura)
        handleRequest(data)
```

Comment: You noticed that you answered your own question? You will just have to find a way to end you program on demand.

Comment: I know, but I wish someone could give me a hint about how I could do that.